# Get point looking at on a plane based on eye angle, head position and orientation, plane of screens

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I have the set up in the image. The set up is an individual looking at 3 screens. What I need to know is where on the screens the individual is looking. I have the position and orientation of the head in space as well as the angle of the eye in the head. What I am wondering is how can I combine this information to get an idea of where on the screens the individual is looking?

Comment: A really simple model would be to add the head angle, the eye angle, and draw a line from the center of the head, and see wher that intersects the screens.

Comment: yeah that sounds like a sensible thing to do but I don't have good maths skills. Would you be able to tell me or point me to some resources that could explain how to calculate the line?